# Logarithmic spiral appears inverted

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polar-coordinates

I'm learning to code the equation for a [logarithmic spiral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSpiral.html) for a graphics visualization. However, it appears to be inverted with the radius getting smaller (rather than larger) toward the outside of the curve. How can I invert the result so the radius gets larger as the curve moves outward?

```
var theta = 1; // begin at theta 1
for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
    // LOG SPIRAL SHAPE
    var a = 500; // a constant
    var b = 0.2; // another constant
    var pX = a * Math.cos(theta) * Math.log(b * theta);
    var pY = a * Math.sin(theta) * Math.log(b * theta);
    theta += 1; // increment theta
    // place an image at pX,pY and repeat
```

Since a picture is worth a thousand words (or lines of code), here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Well, where is your problem? Note the outer "particles" are the ones generated last, but the logarithm grows _very_ slowly. This is why the points are more dense at the outside. And you'll probably want to ensure not to have a negative radius, thus $b\theta \ge 1$ is required. $$$$ Also, the logarithmic spiral, as you can see from the article, needs $\cos \theta \cdot \exp(b\cdot\theta)$, not $\cos(\theta)\cdot \log(b\theta)$

Comment: Also, if you want your spiral to look better, I suspect you should multiply theta by $\pi/180$ before feeding it to the sin and cos functions. Computer trig functions typically assume that the argument is in radians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Math.log(b * theta)` by `Math.exp(b * theta)` and things should agree with the formulas from the article you referenced.